# Removing Row Instances of a Data.Frame based on Column Value of Another Data.Frame

Tags: r

## Background

I have a NxM data.frame `MATRIX_1` in R containing a series of values. In addition to this, I have another NxM data.frame `MATRIX_2` that contains a 1:1 mapping to the first, but instead of numerical values, they are booleans to tell if that data point falls outside 2 standard deviations from the mean of that particular column.

## Goal

I'm wanting to remove all rows from my `MATRIX_1` in which the corresponding `[row, col]` in `MATRIX_2` contains a `TRUE` value.

## Example

```
MATRIX_2
AGE   SEX   BMI    BP    S1    S2    S3    S4    S5    S6     Y PROGRESSION
[1,] FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE       FALSE
```

Above, the `BMI` column has a `TRUE` value in the column. Therefore, this entire row should be removed from the `MATRIX_1` where `MATRIX_1` looks something like the following:

```
MATRIX_1
    AGE SEX  BMI     BP  S1    S2   S3   S4     S5  S6   Y PROGRESSION
1    59   2 32.1 101.00 157  93.2 38.0 4.00 4.8598  87 151           1
```

## Attempt

I've seen some of the following using the `%in%` operator, but want this to auto apply to all columns, whereas something like `df1[!(df1$name %in% df2$name),]` targets specifically a singular column in the frame.

I'm getting almost successful using `subset`

```
subset(diabetes2, boolean_diabetes2[,1] == TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select all rows from `MATRIX_1`, where the corresponding rows in `MATRIX_2` contains all `FALSE` values, you could do:

```
# sample data    
set.seed(1)
MATRIX_2 <- matrix(sample(c(T,F), 3*4, T, prob = c(.3,.7)), ncol=3)
MATRIX_1 <-  as.data.frame(matrix(runif(3*4), ncol=3))

# subsetting
MATRIX_1[!rowSums(MATRIX_2),]
```

Comment: This is great. Do you mind explaining exactly what rowSums is applying in this case?

Comment: @RyanShocker Sure. `rowSums` builds sums per row in MATRIX_2. Each `TRUE` value is counted as `1`. Thus, if there`s any `TRUE` value in a row, the result for that row will be greater 0. `!rowSums(MATRIX_2)` is only TRUE for those rows, which have no `TRUE` value (0 is aequivalent to `FALSE`, which is checked using the `!` operator.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I was looking for.